# Imageview in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have an imageview in row.xml and I set a picture for it in xml layout. But when I use that in adapter (onbindviewholder method)
Not show any image . But when I set image resource in onbindviewholder that works and show the image !!!
What is wrong in the first method ???

Comment: Add code of your adapter

Comment: comment this line when you are setting image from xml.

Comment: holder.yourImageView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
holder.Image.setImageResource();
```

or you can use Glide or Picasso library to load images.

and also return the size of your list.

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.vh> {
    private List<Contacts> contacts;

    public Adapter(List<Contacts> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public class vh extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView first_name;
        protected TextView last_name;
        protected ImageView Image;

        public vh(View v) {
            super(v);
            first_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.first);
            last_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.last);
            Image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Adapter.vh onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new vh(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(vh holder, int position) {
        Contacts example = contacts.get(position);
        holder.first_name.setText(example.name);
        holder.last_name.setText(example.last_name);
        if (position == 3) {
            holder.first_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
    }
}
```