# How to set imageView to an recyclerview viewholder programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I want to assign an ImageView programmatically.

```
public static class RecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView1;
    public TextView textView2;

    public RecyclerViewViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.) // here how to make it programatically?
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262900/imageview-in-a-recyclerview/46263098#46266417

Answer (score 0):

You have to set id of your `imageView` in your viewholder's imageview.

Like this:

```
 imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.**imageView**);
```

here `imageView` is the id of the imageview in the viewholder's XML

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public static class RecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public ImageView imageView;


    public RecyclerViewViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

      LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setId(id);
            imageView.setImageResource(0);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

            linearLayout.addView(imageView);


    }
    }
```